# After npm install of a single package, my build script throws An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Tags: angular, npm

Perhaps this is just my misunderstanding of how npm install works. I'm looking to be educated on how this can happen.

In my angular 10.x project, which builds and runs fine, my current task is to replace the "brace" library with "ace-builds".

As a first step, without changing any code in my working project, I have executed the command:

`npm install ace-builds@1.5.0 --save`

So, all I've done thus far is the above command to install the library to my node_modules so that its available for use and testing.

However, after this install, when I attempt to build and run my project, I now get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Huh? So it appears that the install of ace-builds apparently removed or replaced some libraries that my current app depends on. Even though I have not changed any code in my project to use the newly installed package.

So, as part of that ace-builds install I noticed that I also got this message in the terminal after the install was completed:

> - ace-builds@1.5.0
>   added 1 package, removed 22 packages and audited 2573 packages in 22.993s

"Removed 22 packages"? I suppose that's why my project no longer builds.

Is there a way that I can see which packages where removed so that I can trace the issue to resolve it?

Comment: Update: to fix my project, I deleted the ace-builds reference from my package.json and then ran npm install. That gets me back to a working project. Then, I added the ace-builds reference back to my package.json and ran npm install. That did what I was expecting the direct `npm install @ace-brace@1.5.0 --save` to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: to fix my project, I deleted the ace-builds reference from my package.json and then ran npm install. That gets me back to a working project. Then, I added the ace-builds reference back to my package.json and ran npm install. That did what I was expecting the direct npm install @ace-brace@1.5.0 --save to do